# Bind the datacontext of a Layout

Tags: android, binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, datacontext

I am currently developing an cross-platform application on Android and Windows Phone.

To do that I use Xamarin.Android and the MvvmCross framework.

My Windows Phone application works well and I would like to do something similar in my Xamarin.Android application.

In my Windows Phone app, I have a `UserControl` named `ListProjectsView` which is used in a `ListProjectsSingleView` view. The `ListProjectsSingleViewModel` contains a property for the `ViewModel`, `ListProjectsViewModel`. So I have something like follows in my `ListProjectsSingleViewModel` class:

```
public class ListProjectsSingleViewModel
    : BaseViewModel
{
    private ListProjectsViewModel _listProjectsVM;
    public ListProjectsViewModel ListProjectsVM
    {
        get { return _listProjectsVM; }
        set 
        { 
            _listProjectsVM = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ListProjectsVM);
        }
    }
}
```

In the `ListProjectsSingleView.xaml`, I have something like this to bind the `DataContext` of the `ListProjectsView`:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"
    Orientation="Vertical">
    <myviews:ListProjectsView DataContext="{Binding ListProjectsVM}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This code works well in my Windows Phone application. Now, I want to do the same on Android. To do that, I have an layout `ListProjectsView.axml`. The code for the `ListProjectsSingleViewModel` is the same. Now I want to bind the `ListProjectsVM` on the `DataContext` of my `ListProjectsView` which is contained in the `ListProjectsSingleView`.

To summarize, I just want to know how to bind the `DataContext` of my Android Layout like in Windows Phone but with MvvmCross.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547715/equivalent-to-usercontrol-in-android-with-the-mvvmcross-framework ?

Comment: Not really but the two topics concerns the same problem. I manage to do what I want with a MvxTabActivity with only one Tab. And it works well !