# LayoutInflater exception with MvxFrameControl inside MvxItemTemplate inside MvxListView inside MvxDialogFragment

Tags: mvvmcross

We're working on an Android application using Xamarin for Android and MvvmCross 4.0.0-beta3.

I've run into an issue I can't quite understand. I have a dialog, hosted inside a `MvxDialogFragment`. We're overriding the `OnCreateDialog`-method and returning a Dialog build using the `AltertDialog.Build`. The View is set to the dialog using a view created by calling `this.BindingInflate` in the dialog (the class deriving from MvxDialogFragment).

The view we're inflating is containing a `MvxListView`, and the `MvxItemTemplate` contains a `MvxFrameControl`. When running the app I get the following exception:

`InnerException was MvxException: The owning Context for a MvxFrameControl must implement LayoutInflater`

If I remove the `MvxFrameControl`from the item template, and include something like a `TextView` the dialog renders correctly (and the databound text is displayed).

We have other cases in our app where the `MvxFrameControl` is used from an item template, which renders just fine, and we have dialogs containing `MvxFrameControl`. It seems the problem only occurs when the structure is `MvxDialogFragment -> MvxListView -> MvxItemTemplate -> MvxFrameControl`.

Looking at the [code for the MvxFrameControl](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxFrameControl.cs#L39) you can see that it throws the exception we're receiving if the context doesn't implement `IMvxLayoutInflaterHolder`.

So; my question is something like this: what ends up beeing the "owning context" when the `MvxFrameControl` is hosted like mentioned above?

Comment: What purpose does the MvxFrameControl have in your layout?

Comment: Reusable component - we're binding the datacontext and using the MvxFrameControl to reuse a view.

Comment: I can't really see why you would do it that way. Can you make an isolated small sample which reproduces this?

Comment: We're using the MvxFrameControl as an equivalent to a user control. I'll see if I can create a small example app reproducing the error. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547715/equivalent-to-usercontrol-in-android-with-the-mvvmcross-framework